# "SQLite Error 20: 'datatype mismatch'.'" error while peforming migration with SQLite table rebuild in .NET 5.0-preview7 project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have simple class library project with a **EF Core 5.0-rc1** DbContext that targets **.NET 5.0-preview7** with following entites:

```
public class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Int32 Age { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public String Text { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I've added first migration via `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate` command, created test database and populated some data.
After that I've changed **Post.Id** data type from **Guid** to **Int32** and created second migration.

According to **[this](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/329)** SQLite migrations table rebuilds are now available since **EF Core 5.0.0-preview8**.
Also according to **[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations)** **AlterColumn** command should work for SQLite via table rebuild.

But running `context.Database.Migrate();` throws an exception

> SQLite Error 20: 'datatype mismatch'.'

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Download **[test project](https://yadi.sk/d/iZiJnlidwyNMlg)** (test database test.db with some data
   is already placed in program output folder).
2. Compile and run Test console application - `context.Database.Migrate();` throws an
   exception

**Exception StackTrace:**

> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32
> rc, sqlite3 db)    at
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()    at
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> behavior)    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject
> parameterObject)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection
> connection, IReadOnlyDictionary' 2 parameterValues)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1
> migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String
> targetMigration)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade
> databaseFacade)    at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> D:\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 14

**Further technical details**

1. EF Core version: **5.0-rc1**
2. Database provider: **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 5.0-rc1**
3. Target framework: **.NET 5.0-preview7**
4. Operating system: **Windows 10 2004 x64**
5. IDE: **Visual Studio 2019 16.7.3 Professional**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like SQLite teble rebuild is not a magic bullet and work a little differently than I expected. In case of changing data type for a column you should manually write all migrations - [check full discussion with EF team](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22598).